# Breaking IP address into octets but skip first octet with sscanf

Tags: c++, c

```
unsigned short octet2, octet3, octet4;
sscanf(ipAddr.c_str(), "%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &octet2, &octet2, &octet3, &octet4);
```

ipAddr is a string.

From the above code, it is successfully breaking the octets up. However, I'd like to just avoid touching the first octet of the IP address. I want to avoid extra operations of writing into octet2 twice.

For example, with the IP address 1.2.3.4, I'll break up the IP address into 2, then 3, then 4 without touching 1.

My operations will be done over a million times, unless there is a better method than sscanf please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried this `sscanf(ipAddr.c_str(), "%*hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &octet2, &octet2, &octet3, &octet4);` the * is for ignoring it after reading the value

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: problem is `&` instead of `%`...

Comment: Oh typo, fixed it

Comment: besides, I'm not sure of behaviour of that `sscanf(ipAddr.c_str(), "%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &octet2, &octet2, &octet3, &octet4);`. Which argument is evaluated first in `scanf` since you're reusing the same variable. Not sure it's left to right. Well, maybe.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre a byte is not an octet on all systems. IP address always consists of octets on all systems, regardless of byte size.

Comment: @user2079303 betrayed by too much (or not enough:)) knowledge: "octet" is french for "bytes"! will revert OP edit.

Comment: sscanf goes from left to right

Comment: Have you bench-marked this? Memory bandwidth in a new PC is somewhere in the range 10-20 GB/s, and a million writes of `short` will be 2 MB. Is this a problem to focus on?

Comment: Just being nit picky, and I want to understand millisecond improvements more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could scan but not store the first argument by prefixing first format specifier by `*` to tell `sscanf` to parse but not store the field (and you only need 3 parameters in that case):

```
sscanf(ipAddr.c_str(), "%*hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", &octet2, &octet3, &octet4);
```